# Remote Apache Logging

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat, rsyslog

I have been researching remote logging of apache logs, and everything I have found involves piping to logger.

Two questions:

1. Is there any other way to remotely log apache logs?
2. Is piping to
   logger stable?

Thank you!

Jeff

Comment: In your research, what you want to be looking for is something called a 'log shipper'. When considering which log-shipper to use, you should look at what other logs you might like to ship (eg. do you want windows event logs? do you care about having to have Java installed for some log-shippers? do you want to ship logs as json? ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) As indicated by the tag, rsyslog can do this. Write the logs to a file and use http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/imfile.html .

2) Yes. `logger` is a stable program apache's piping mechanism is stable (e.g., piping to `rotatelogs` has been in use for quite a while).

Comment: I think you need at least version 7 of rsyslog to tail a file. It is unfortunate that some distribution version in current lifecycle have version 5.

Answer (score 2):

We use [logstash](http://www.logstash.net/), an open source log aggregating tool. It can pull in Apache logs from multiple machines and also logs from many other applications. The best approach is to format the output of apache httpd logs in json format with something like this:

```
LogFormat "{ \"@timestamp\": \"%{%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z}t\", \"@fields\": { \"client\": \"%{X-Forwarded-For}i\", \"virtualhost\": \"%{Host}i\", \"duration_usec\": %D, \"status\": %s, \"request\": \"%U%q\", \"method\": \"%m\", \"referrer\": \"%{Referer}i\" } }" logstash_json
```

Then install logstash and have it collect all your logs into a central server. It is reliable, survives network outages (logstash remembers where it got up to) and has a very pretty UI with searching capability.

Answer (score 1):

> 2. Is piping to logger stable?

Many many programs pipe their output to `logger`. It is as stable as any other piece of software.

`logger` is simple and just works. `logger` makes use of your existing syslog configuration. It doesn't need any tweaks to syslog or rsyslog, and there is no need to grant superuser to users who need logs. Logger sends logs to syslog on the local system, and syslog handles the rest.

Note that syslog historically uses UDP, and UDP is intended to be a low-overhead, 'unreliable' protocol. See [RFC5426 - "Transmission of Syslog Messages over UDP"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5426#section-4), section "4. Reliability Considerations". If you want reliable syslog, use TLS, see [RFC5425, Transport Layer Security (TLS) Transport Mapping for Syslog](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5425).